# How to convert character names to character codes on linux

Tags: ubuntu, character-encoding

I'm looking for a way to convert the character names found in the files in the 
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ folder like:

```
key <AE01> { [ 1, copyright, registered, trademark ] };
key <AE03> { [ 3, numbersign, section, paragraph ] };
key <AE04> { [ 4, EuroSign, dollar, sterling ] };
key <AE11> { [ masculine, ordfeminine, dead_circumflex, dead_caron ] };
key <AE12> { [apostrophe, asterisk, plus, dead_abovering ] };
key <AD11> { [dead_acute, dead_grave, dead_diaeresis, dead_macron ] };
key <AD12> { [question, exclam, questiondown, slash ] };
key <AC10> { [ ccedilla, Ccedilla, dead_acute, dead_doubleacute ] };
key <AC11> { [dead_tilde, dead_circumflex, dead_diaeresis, dead_breve] };
key <TLDE> { [ backslash, bar, notsign, notsign ] };

key <BKSL> { [question, exclam, questiondown, slash ] };
```

to character codes. can you help me? i thing there must be a file listing these, but i cannot find it. by the way, i'm using ubuntu 10.04.

Thanks in advance, Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all here, in the Git repository: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/xproto/tree/keysymdef.h